# What is a word for purposely trying to avoid answering a question?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a verb for someone trying to avoid the question at hand by digressing. Or to mess up the answer so as to create confusion? Or to give a vague answer?

(At the back of my mind, there is a word that is something like 'subfugate' - which is not an actual word I realised - but something similiar or along those letters? Or I could be plain mistaken)

Comment: Probably "***subterfuge"***,but that is not related only to questions: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/subterfuge

Comment: @Josh61 exactly the word that I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: You are *evading* the question.

Comment: Were you thinking of ***obfuscate*** ? This is the word to use when evasion is achieved by clouding the issue. Creating a smoke-screen.

Comment: ***Equivocate*** is what i would use.

Answer (score 3):

I thought you were looking for a verb. If you're still looking for a verb:

Prevaricate, evade, dodge.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/evade?s=t

Answer (score 2):

Consider, ***fudge***.

> : (v.i.) to avoid coming to grips with something : *to fudge on an issue*.
>
> : (v.t.) to avoid coming to grips with (a subject, issue, etc.); evade; dodge [Random House](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fudge)

You can also ***circumvent*** a question.

> circumvent: to avoid or try to avoid fulfilling, answering, or performing [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/circumvent)

Answer (score 1):

What you describe sounds like **dodging the question**:

> Question dodging is the intentional avoidance of answering a question.

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_dodging)

In the context of politics, another word for this kind of trick would be **pivot** (it's a noun, but I think you can verb it):

> Brett O'Donnell is a **debate consultant who trains Republican candidates**. He has worked with George W. Bush and John McCain, and for a short time earlier this year, he helped prep Mitt Romney.
>
> O'Donnell is an expert on "the pivot."
>
> If you have watched a debate, you have watched a pivot. **"The *pivot* is a way of taking a question that might be on a specific subject, and moving to answer it on your own terms,"** O'Donnell says.

(http://www.npr.org/2012/10/03/162103368/how-politicians-get-away-with-dodging-the-question)

Pivoting to answer the question "on your own terms" may result in all kinds of shenanigans: obfuscation, digressing, changing the subject, etc.