# Is there another one-word substitute for officialese?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I wanted to use a one-word expression for a written communication (short or long) which is a response to a question. It is deliberately worded to evade answering the question, using very distinctively official language. In short, it leaves the reader confused whether the question was answered at all. If yes, then what actually was the answer.

My sentence would be something like:

> "He has mastered the art of .....  "

or

> "He has mastered the art of using ....."

Comment: Have you considered "hedging"?

Comment: ... Trying to figure out if I should upvote answers, or exceptionally crafted [non-answers](https://www.npr.org/2017/03/21/520995993/how-nominees-master-the-art-of-the-non-answer-in-senate-hearings). You could say Orwelian language, which is itself [doublespeak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doublespeak) since he invented several different and contradictory ones.

Comment: Does the answer have to be “safe for work”? Have you considered “bullshit”?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I've understood completely, but assuming a bureaucracy is official, then maybe:

> [bureaucratese](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bureaucratese)
>  a style of language held to be characteristic of
>   bureaucrats and marked by abstractions, jargon, euphemisms, and
>   circumlocutions.

"Circumlocutions" here doesn't have a positive note, though I'm not sure if it's implying evasiveness.

> "He has mastered the art of bureaucratese," --- "and easily managed to avoid giving a forthright response."

By the way "offialese" is also a word.

> [officialese](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/officialese)
>  Language characteristic of official documents or
>   statements, especially when obscure, pretentiously wordy, or
>   excessively formal.

Answer (score 1):

Obfuscation or [obfuscate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obfuscate):

> 1 b : to make obscure - obfuscate the issue - officials who … continue to obscure and obfuscate what happened — Mary Carroll

These other threads might have something relevant:

- [a word for purposely trying to avoid answering a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286215/what-is-a-word-for-purposely-trying-to-avoid-answering-a-question)
- [a response which does not address the question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/215722/what-do-you-call-a-response-which-does-not-address-the-question)

Answer (score 0):

School officials are fond of **edubabble**. I’d find you some examples, but it’s too depressing to look for them.

However if you google “achievement gap” you will likely find the Wikipedia article, where

> home and community environments have a stronger impact on school achievement than in-school factors, in part, because students spend more time outside of school than in school. In addition, the out-of-school factors influencing academic performance differ significantly between children living in poverty and children from middle-income households.

Expressed more simply: if your parents are poor and you live in a poor neighborhood, you are less likely to do well at school.

Edubabble is characterized by a deep reluctance to speak plainly. A poor person might reasonably ask how his or her lot might be improved, but with all these complicating factors and ten-dollar words, people lose focus and action gets deflected.

Answer (score 0):

As long ago as the mid-nineteenth century, the English author Trollope placed some of his characters as officials in the Circumlocution Office. As others have pointed out, officialese and bureaucratese are recognised English words. If you find those words distasteful and ugly, as I do, then "circumlocution" would surely work.