# What's the word for someone who avoids answering a question with their opinion instead?

Tags: questions, social-interaction

For example -

**Questioner**: What do I need to know about the system of emigrating to New Zealand? **I hate the weather here...**

**Answer**: Moving to New Zealand because you hate the weather isn't a good reason to emigrate...[*continue to express their opinions on your decision*].

Instead of addressing the question, the answering individual decides to express an unsolicited opinion on the decision or motivations for the person asking for advice about a particular action. The questioner didn't ask his opinion about the reason why he is emigrating, but more so 'how' to emigrate.

This type of behaviour tends to be *very* commonplace in both the real world and in online forums.

Comment: What’s the word for attaching irrelevant statements of opinion to the end of legitimate questions?  If the questioner hadn’t added it, the Answerer wouldn’t address it.  By adding it, the questioner makes it relevant.

Comment: It depends on your point of view. If you like it (you don't seem to), you might say they are *reframing* the question or *exploring* the motives. If you don't like it, you might say they are *avoiding the question* or *being argumentative*.  As for what to call them, *helpful* or *insightful* in the first case, *annoying* in the latter. As @Jim said, if you want an answer to a specific question and only that question, then ask only that question.

Comment: @Jim Especially when the speaker **shouts** the extraneous statement, and doesn't add a politeness marker to the question. Here, it's using free will to choose to address the comment rather than the question.

Comment: When the question is considered in need of refinement, it's called constructive criticism on ELU. I'd suggest << Questioner (to an official who knows that the better weather in New Zealand is the reason I want to emigrate): 'What do I need to know about the system of emigrating to New Zealand, please?' >>

Comment: I would call them *irritating* but please see: [What is a word for purposely trying to avoid answering a question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286215/what-is-a-word-for-purposely-trying-to-avoid-answering-a-question) and its duplicate. And as mentioned, the questioner has diverted from the question without waiting for an answer with their *own* opinion, so what else can be expected? Even *more* irritating is when people ask questions but are not interested in an answer.

Comment: There is probably a psychological diagnosis for that particular malady, but I don't know what it would be.

Comment: *Attention seeking*? *Opinionated*? It depends entirely on the motivation behind the response.

Comment: @Jim - Your comment presents a perfect example.

Comment: @DanJHillComposer - Glad you noticed.  ;-)

Comment: In politics, isn't that *pivoting*?