# What's a word that describes the type of person that unintentionally answers a question with related info without answering the question specifically?

Tags: meaning

Imagine you are talking to an older person and you ask, "What is the sun made of?" To which they reply, "It was a cold day today, but I was sitting on the park bench earlier and felt pretty warm in the sunlight."

They were able to talk about something that was related to the question, but obviously did not answer it. What is a word that describes this state of being? I'm fairly certain that there is a more specific term for this, but the only words coming to mind are "spacious" and "gaseous" (as a state of being, not as a description of composition).

I was listening to a podcast in which the host was interviewing someone that seemed to be elderly. The host would ask questions of the interviewee but would not get exact answers in return. The answers would either be related to the question (like above), or they wouldn't be related at all. Some people might say that the person being asked the questions "isn't all there" mentally, but that's more of an observation of the state of being and not a description of the state of being itself.

I'm having difficulty with figuring out how to accurately ask this question, so there's some serious irony in here somewhere.

Edit:
The suggested duplicate question does not answer the question. The word I was looking for was "vacant".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a word for purposely trying to avoid answering a question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286215/what-is-a-word-for-purposely-trying-to-avoid-answering-a-question) {'Is there a [word] for someone trying to avoid the question at hand by digressing? Or to mess up the answer so as to create confusion? Or to give a vague answer?} (plus a duplicate).

Comment: According to your stories, spaciness is caused by old-ness. Let's all agree not to pass 40.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No, the state of being described here is not necessarily an intentional one, whereas that question is intentional.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - I wish I could still agree to that.

Comment: @YosefBaskin That's the only group of individuals in which I've seen this exemplified, so I was hoping it would be easier to ascertain the full meaning of my question by giving a seemingly relatable experience.

Comment: I think the word(s) you would use depend entirely on the reason for,  or cause of, the behavior.

Comment: Their response was unfocused. This refers (by transference) to their state of mind, as well as to the fuzzy response.